# What is rotation of magnetization?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

Actually I recently started learning about ferromagnetism and I encountered this in Wikipedia article [Magnetic hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_hysteresis?wprov=sfla1):

> The phenomenon of hysteresis in ferromagnetic materials is the result of two effects: rotation of magnetization and changes in size or number of magnetic domains.

The article is about magnetic hysteresis and it explains what causes hysteresis in the ferromagnetic material.

Can you please explain what does rotating
of magnetization mean? Does that mean rotation of Magnetization function in the hysterian loop?

(I'm really confused now. Please apologise me if i made a serious error or the question is so stupid.)

Comment: I think it must mean the little magnetic dipoles rotating around to end up pointing in a different direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can think of a domain as a region where many atoms line up so that the magnetic field they produce add together to produce a resultant magnetic field.
Imagine that magnetic field as being produced by a bar magnet with a domain.
If the bar magnet was rotated, ie direction in which the bar magnet pointed changed, then the magnetic field associated with the bar magnet (magnetization of the domain) would have change/rotated.
[image]

In the highly stylised images the sizes and shapes of the domains has not changed but you will note that the magnetisation of some of the domains (shown in green) has.